# Run Long running tasks in Broadcast receiver OnReceive Method and Fetch User location

Tags: android, flutter

I have a situation where my app has to fetch user location from `LocationManager` for specified intervals of time. I previously used Services with Location Listener and fetch the location. But due to restriction in some ROM like MI, EMIUI I am unable to use Service and run in background. And one more Use case is i need to run in strict time schedules for which I used `AlarmManager` and triggered Broadcast. In`onReceive` Method I use location listener and started and run a time out mechanism for 2 min say. if the location is available in `onLocation` method it logs and turns off all the handlers and listeners and if the timeout occurs then it resets and logs null. This is happening when the screen is on and if the operation are fast. Sometimes I don't see null logs. Can any one explain me the reason and suggest me the solution?

Here is the code sample of the Async Task which I am invoking from the Receiver, Actual one is quite similar to it:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
public class AsyncTest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    private Location currentLocation;

    private DBHelper helper;

    private Context context;

    public AsyncTest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        helper = new DBHelper(context);
        try {


            timer = new Timer();
            timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (currentLocation == null) {
                        helper.insert(new UserLoc(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString(), -1, -1, "Some Mode", "No Location Data"));
                        Log.d("Timer Timeout", "Success");
                    }
                }
            };

            timer.schedule(timerTask, 2 * 60 * 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            helper.insert(new UserLoc(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString(), -1, -1, "Some Mode", e.getMessage()));
            ;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you tried, and the error you got ? Thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#effects-process-state

Comment: @pskink, I have looked into it and have implemented using Async Task and put a timer in it, but iam still not able to log data when screen is off

Comment: The timer is scheduled to run after two minutes after invoking but fails in some cases like when screen is off and get no logs for that and no exceptions raised.

Comment: did you see: *"For this reason, you should not start long running background threads from a broadcast receiver. After onReceive(), the system can kill the process at any time to reclaim memory, and in doing so, it terminates the spawned thread running in the process."*? read the section i linked carefully

Comment: *I have even tried with Services, but in MI mobiles the roms are not allowing my background service to run and they are stopping it soon the app is removed from App tray*